# When to use recursive relationship?

Tags: entity-relationship

There are two situation one is double line(recursive), the other is normal

[image]

[image]

Could anyone explain why the first one use recursive and the second not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, a cow could be both an owner and owned by.  For example, a cow could be owned by another cow in a parent-child relationship.  A cow could also be owned by a farmer.

In the second example, a student cannot attend another student.  There isn't any recursive relationship there.

Comment: I may be wrong at the notation, does the double like a full participation  notation? please have a look my new question about i t http://stackoverflow.com/q/19781294/456218