# What's the difference in notation for total participation and recursive relation?

Tags: entity-relationship, relationship

Does the double line in the following ER diagrams means total participation or recursive relation?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Could anyone tell me the notation difference for both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Total Participation:** Every entity in the set is involved in some association (or tuple) of the relationship.

**Recursive Relationship:** An entity set relating to itself.

Most commonly in recursive relationships they indicate the different types of roles an entity can have (e.g., the different ways it can participate) in a relationship by writing each role above each line.

An example of this would be in a `Course` table with a relational table of `Prerequisites`

A `Course` could be both the `Prerequisite` and the `Course` and you would write those on each line.

Here's another [example](https://wofford-ecs.org/DataAndVisualization/ermodel/images/fig12.jpg).

Assuming your textbook follows a similar pattern, I would assume that these are in fact total participation constraints.

Comment: So the double lines in all three are totally participation?

Comment: That's what I would assume since they don't have the words on each line.  But, if I were you, I would go through your textbook when they first introduce the notation and double check.  It's hard to know the semantics of the textbook.

Answer (score 3):

**double line** : Used to represent total participation of an entity in a relationship set.

A **recursive relationship** is one in which the same entity participates more than once in the relationship.

recursive relationship example : *Suppose one team is assigned the task of supervising the other teams. This supervisor team makes sure that each team records its portion of the data. The supervision relationship is a recursive relationship because the same entity, a particular team, participates more than once in the relationship, as a supervisor and as a supervisee. To draw the situation, we label the two lines between team and supervision with the two possible roles*

by this definitions all three above are total participation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

defination of total participation constraints: the participation of an entoty set E in the eelationship R is said to be a total if every entity in E participates in at least one relationship in R.